# Async UIView content not showing up when coming back to main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

When loading my UIViewController, I basically put a spinner in the middle of the page until the content loads, then come back on the main thread to add the subviews :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *aiv_loading = ... // etc

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Load content
        NSString *s_checkout = [[BRNetwork sharedNetwork] getCheckoutInstructionsForLocation:self.locBooking.location];
        UIView *v_invoice_content = [[BRNetwork sharedNetwork] invoiceViewForBooking:locBooking.objectId];

        // Display the content
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if (s_checkout && v_invoice_content) {
                [aiv_loading removeFromSuperview];
                [self showContentWithText:s_checkout AndInvoice:v_invoice_content];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"No data received!"); // is thankfully not called
            }
        });
    });
}

- (void) showContentWithText:(NSString *)s_checkout AndInvoice:(UIView *)v_invoice {

    [self.view addSubview:[self checkoutTextWithText:s_checkout]]; // Most of the time displayed text
    [self.view addSubview:[self completeCheckout]]; // always Displayed UIButton
    [self.view addSubview:[self divider]]; // always displayed UIImageView

    // Summary title
    UILabel *l_summary = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [self divider].frame.origin.y + 6 + 10, self.view.bounds.size.width, 20)];
    l_summary.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Summary", nil);
    [self.view addSubview:l_summary];

    CGRect totalRect = CGRectMake([self divider].frame.origin.x, [self divider].frame.origin.y + 6 + 30, self.view.bounds.size.width - [self divider].frame.origin.x, 90);
    _v_invoice = v_invoice;
    _v_invoice.frame = totalRect;
    [self.view addSubview:[self v_invoiceWithData:v_invoice]]; // THIS Pretty much never displayed

    UITextView *l_invoice = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, _v_invoice.frame.origin.y + _v_invoice.frame.size.height + offset, 320.0, 50)];
    l_invoice.text = NSLocalizedString(@"summary_emailed", nil);
    [self.view addSubview:l_invoice]; // Always displayed
}
```

However, not all the content is displayed. The invoice is never there at first, but gets displayed after a couple of minutes. The other async-created string, s_content is sometimes not displayed.

This seems to be random with the content creation. The end result is pretty neat, but not reliable for a production version.

I used the undocumented [self.view recursiveDescription] to check if everything was there, and even if I don't see it, they are all there with what seems to be correct frames.

Any pointers? 
- layoutSubviews did not help!
- putting a background color to the invoice view is showing the background color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this line is your problem:

```
UIView *v_invoice_content = [[BRNetwork sharedNetwork] invoiceViewForBooking:locBooking.objectId];
```

As you are calling this in a background dispatch queue. Any work involving UIKit should be done on the main queue/thread. Either move that into the main thread block, or if building the view is dependent on data from a network call, change your `invoiceViewForBooking` method to return the data first, and build your view in the main thread with that data.

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Load content
        NSString *s_checkout = [[BRNetwork sharedNetwork] getCheckoutInstructionsForLocation:self.locBooking.location];
        id someData = [[BRNetwork sharedNetwork] invoiceDataForBooking:locBooking.objectId];

        // Display the content
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIView *v_invoice_content = [invoiceViewWithData:someData];
        });
    });
```

I'd also suggest using `dispatch_async` instead of `dispatch_sync` on the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I ended up removing the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)`
To only leave the async block on the main queue:

```
// Display the content from a new async block on the main queue.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [aiv_loading removeFromSuperview];
    NSString *s_checkout = [[BRNetwork sharedNetwork] getCheckoutInstructionsForLocation:self.locBooking.location];
    [self showContentWithText:s_checkout AndInvoice:[[BRNetwork sharedNetwork] invoiceViewForBooking:locBooking.objectId]];
});
```

which did the trick, viewcontroller's view can appear without waiting for the view to load the remote data!

Answer (score -1):

You should put your code in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`.  Whatever is related to display (even launching async blocks) should always be in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

Also, I recommend you to use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{})` instead of your `dispatch_sync` since you still want your block to be performed async (but on main thread).

Dont forget to call super methods in your `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` your view should already be loaded so you can display anything you want there and especially if you you don't want to redisplay something every time your view is displayed, you **should** use `viewDidLoad`. Where did you see that suggestion?

Comment: Just tried but unfortunately did not change anything! What is really hard to understand is that the content is there when checking the subviews of self.view, right frames, right text, but nothing is displayed

Comment: @Ivan Genchev There is cases where your view frame will not be accurate in `viewDidLoad`, and layoutSubviews haven't been called yet.  Also, there is a few UIView animations being performed by iOS while presenting the views that could shortcircuit presentation codes put in `viewDidLoad`.  I agree though that one-time-only code should be elsewhere, or enclosed in a check like `if (isFirstAppearance)`, since `viewDidAppear` is executed whenever the view comes back into focus.

Comment: It did not solve the issue, but this is a good point! when I put a red backgroundcolor, I see it, only its subviews loaded from another view are invisible

Comment: @Séraphin Hochart I'm not quite sure how should react a view creation in an async thread.  I may suggest you to move the view creation code from `invoiceViewForBooking` to your `showContentWithText`, and instead make `invoiceViewForBooking` return whatever data you need to build your view and pass it along to `showContentWithText` as you did with s_checkout.