# UIView not removing from sight, but removing from "click ability"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a UIview that is just a semi-transparent screen cover with the word "Loading" on it. and one of those spinning activity icons.

After loading, I need to remove the loading view from the UI, but for whatever reason, this is not happening. Here's the method in question.

```
- (void) readyForRoomDisplay
{
    [_loadingIcon stopAnimating]; //_loadingIcon is the activity spinner
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:_loadingView]; // an attempt to hide
    [_loadingView setHidden:YES]; // an attempt to hide
    [_loadingView removeFromSuperview];// an attempt to hide
    [self nextRoom:_roomImageButton];//should refresh the whole view
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The kicker is, after this happens, the contents of the VC's main view (while obscured) are clickable!!!

Some screenshots:

**Normal Loading Image before AND after it should be destroyed**
[image: Load Screen]

**Somehow, I'm able to click THROUGH the loading screen!**
[image: Clicking through the load screen]

**This is the normal app main screen and appears when the button is clicked to swap calendars (refreshing the screen)**
[image: Normal App main screen]

I feel like I've done everything that one can possibly do to get this out of here. It appears that the view is not updating after getting these commands. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looked here: [Async UIView content not showing up when coming back to main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552056/async-uiview-content-not-showing-up-when-coming-back-to-main-thread?rq=1)

Apparently this update was not happening on the main thread, I just needed to push it back to the main thread an all was saved! Huzzah!